# Parsing JSON object in RUBY with a wildcard?

Tags: json, ruby

**Problem**:

I'm relatively new to programming and learning Ruby, I've worked with JSON before but have been stumped by this problem.

I'm taking a hash, running hash.to_json, and returning a json object that looks like this:
'quantity' =

```
{
"line_1": {
    "row": "1",
    "productNumber": "111",
    "availableQuantity": "4"
},
"line_2": {
    "row": "2",
    "productNumber": "112",
    "availableQuantity": "6"
},
"line_3": {
    "row": "3",
    "productNumber": "113",
    "availableQuantity": "10"
}
```

I want to find the 'availableQuantity' value that's greater than 5 and return the line number.
Further, I'd like to return the line number and the product number.

**What I've tried**

1. I've been searching on using a wildcard in a JSON query to get over the "line_" value for each entry, but with no luck.
2. to simply identify a value for 'availableQuantity' within the JSON object greater than 5:

   q = JSON.parse(quantity)

   q.find {|key| key["availableQuantity"] > 5}

However this returns the error: "*{TypeError}no implicit conversion of String into Integer*."
I've googled this error but I can not understand what it means in the context of this problem.

or even

```
q.find {|key, value| value > 2}
```

which returns the error: "*undefined method `>' for {"row"=>"1", "productNumber"=>111, "availableQuantity"=>4}:Hash*"

This attempt looks so simplistic I'm ashamed, but it reveals a fundamental gap in my understanding of how to work with looping over stuff using enumerable.

Can anyone help explain a solution, and ideally what the steps in the solution mean? For example, does the solution require use of an enumerable with find? Or does Ruby handle a direct query to the json?

This would help my learning considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find the 'availableQuantity' value that's greater than 5 and [...] return the line number and the product number.

First problem: your `value` is not a number, so you can't compare it to `5`. You need `to_i` to convert.

Second problem: getting the line number is easiest with regular expressions. `/\d+/` is "any consecutive digits". Combining that...

```
q.select { |key, value|
  value['availableQuantity'].to_i > 5
}.map { |key, value|
  [key[/\d+/].to_i, value['productNumber'].to_i]
}
# => [[2, 112], [3, 113]]
```

Comment: 'to_i' - of course!  I'm comparing an integer to a string.
And the regex used to isolate any consecutive digits is great.
This has helped a lot - thanks very much Amadan.